# Responds method in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I'm trying to let Angular JS and Ruby on Rails communicate for sharing some data in an example application.

I generated a resource called `Entries`, and made this controller:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  def index
    respond_with Entry.all
  end
  def show
    respond_with Entry.find(params[:id])
  end
  def create
    respond_with Entry.create(params[:entry])
  end
  def update
    respond_with Entry.update(params[:id], params[:entry])
  end
  def destroy
    respond_with Entry.destroy(params[:id])
  end
end
```

This generates a response in json with the `Entries` data. I seeded the `Entries` database:

```
# This file should contain all the record creation needed to seed the database with its default values.
# The data can then be loaded with the rake db:seed (or created alongside the db with db:setup).
#
# Examples:
#
#   cities = City.create([{ name: 'Chicago' }, { name: 'Copenhagen' }])
#   Mayor.create(name: 'Emanuel', city: cities.first)

Entry.create!(name: "name1")
Entry.create!(name: "name2")
Entry.create!(name: "name3")
Entry.create!(name: "name4")
Entry.create!(name: "name5")
Entry.create!(name: "name6")
Entry.create!(name: "name7")
```

I created some entries. I need to let Angular receive them. This is my js file:

```
    var rafflerApp = angular.module('rafflerApp', ["ngResource"]);

rafflerApp.controller('RaffleCtrl', function ($scope, $resource) {

  //entries list 
  Entry = $resource("/entries/:id", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}})
  $scope.entries = Entry.query();

  //add a name to the list
  $scope.addEntry = function(entry){
    entry = Entry.save($scope.newEntry);
    $scope.entries.push(entry);
    $scope.newEntry = {}
  } 

  //draw a winner
  $scope.selectWinner = function(draw){
    pool = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.entries, function(entry){
        if (!entry.winner){
          pool.push(entry)  
        }
    });
    if (pool.length > 0){
        entry = pool[Math.floor(Math.random()*pool.length)]
        entry.winner = true
        entry.$update(entry)
        $scope.lastWinner = entry   
    } 
  }
});
```

If I try the application, I don't receive any js errors, but the list is empty. If I try to navigate to `/entries/(casual :id)`, I receive this error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in EntriesController#index
```

and it highlights this part of the code:

```
def index
  respond_with Entry.all
end
```

Why did I receive this error? How can I let Ruby on Rails communicate data with Angular JS? I am also adding my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :entries
  root to: "raffle#index"
end
```

Comment: have you tried visiting localhost:3000/entries.json from browser ?

Comment: show your `config/routes.rb` file

Comment: @SahilGrover yes, i've tried to navigate to my browser and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Update your `route.rb` to render JSON by default instead HTML

```
resources :entities, defaults: {format: :json}
```

Comment: it still doesn't work. doing some test i've checked that the console log show this message doing the refresh of the page  [HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable] when i try to recive data from http://localhost:3000/entries.

Comment: What are the headers that are getting passed with the request?